# Maximum likelihood lognormal R and SAS

Tags: r, statistics, sas

I am converting SAS codes to R and there is a feature of using lognormal distribution in the SAS univariate procedure using histograms and midpoints. The result is a table containing the following variables,

> *EXPPCT*  -  estimated percent of population in histogram interval determined from optional fitted distribution (here it is lognormal)
>
> *OBSPCT*  -  percent of variable values in histogram interval
>
> *VAR*   -  variable name
>
> *MIDPT*  -  midpoint of histogram interval

There is an option in SAS to consider the MLE of the `zeta`, `theta` and `sigma` parameters while applying the distribution.

Now I was able to figure out the way to do this in R. My only problem arises in the likelihood estimation, when the three parameters are being estimated in SAS. R gives me different values.

I am using the following for MLE in R.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
set.seed(0)
cd <- rlnorm(40,4)
pars <- coef(fitdist(cd, "lnorm"))
```

```r
  meanlog     sdlog 
4.0549354 0.8620153
```

I am using the following for MLE in SAS. (the `est` option)

```
proc univariate data = testing;
histogram cd /lognormal (theta = est zeta=est sigma=est)
midpoints = 1 to &maxx. by 100
outhistogram = this;
run;
```

&maxx denotes the maximum of the input. The results of the run from SAS can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vuVnextvlHXiwo5y5DN_LAj7PXjV_96pKL-tgRe35v0/edit?usp=sharing).

I am new to statistics and unable to find the method used for the MLE in SAS and have no clue as to how to estimate the same in R.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to plot the data, histograms, and fitted distributions in both softwares to see what matches and what doesn't?

Comment: I have updated the document with SAS plot [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vuVnextvlHXiwo5y5DN_LAj7PXjV_96pKL-tgRe35v0/edit?usp=sharing). I went through the SAS documentation and after several trial and error have found that the threshold parameter is estimated and using that the other two parameters, shape and scale are estimated. Can this be done in R?

Comment: I get the same histogram in R at least (using `hist(cd, breaks=0:7*100-50)`).

Comment: The same estimate of the distribution too so there has to be a difference in how the parameters are reported. Try it yourself with `hist(cd, breaks=0:7*100-50, freq=FALSE, ylim=c(0, .012)); curve(dlnorm(x, meanlog = pars[1], sdlog=pars[2]), add=TRUE)`.

Comment: I will try it, sure. Any way we can estimate the threshold in R?

Answer (score 0):

I found these packages `EnvStats` and `FAdist` that let me estimate the threshold parameter and use these parameters to fit the 3 parameter lognormal distribution. Backlin was right about the parameters. Right now, the parameters are not an exact match but the end result is the same as SAS. Thank you vey much.